# javascript loading before serverside image is deployed

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Here is my Javascript

```
<%-- script to load the default image--%>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        // Get the canvas element.
        var elem = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
        if (!elem || !elem.getContext) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the canvas 2d context.
        var context = elem.getContext('2d');
        if (!context || !context.drawImage) {
            return;
        }

        // Create a new image.
        var img = new Image();

        // Once it's loaded draw the image on the canvas.
        img.addEventListener('load', function () {


            // Crop and resize the image: sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh.
            context.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 400, 300);
        }, false);
        var imgid = '<%=defaultImage.ClientID %>'
        img.src = document.getElementById(imgid).src;
    }, false);
// --></script>
```

If you look at the img.src at the very bottom, it loads the defaultImage.ClientId from the server which is suppose to get the image on the page.  If I use a normal url it works, but if I use `document.getElementById(imgid).src` it just doesnt load an image.  I am assuming its because the javascript loads before the serverside code is ran.  How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript in Document.Ready()... Also this might be due to the image is in another control..

Comment: or call the function from within the Document.Ready() ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Put the JS at the bottom of your HTML, not the top in this case.